# how to save model.get_weight in form of array to csv?

Tags: python, csv, keras

I am a beginner who is starting learn to code in Keras backend Tensorflow. I am using python 2.7

I have model in keras and after training i want to check my weight.

> Edited

```
# fix random seed for reproducibility (split training and validation set)
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

# load data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# reshape to be [samples][pixels][width][height]
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32')

# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
X_train = X_train / 255
X_test = X_test / 255

# one hot encode outputs (label encoding)
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]

def tempsigmoid(x, temp=0.5):
    return K.sigmoid(x/temp)


def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(1, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Dense, input_shape = (1,28,28), Activation='relu')
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation=tempsigmoid))

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1), metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

    # build the model
model = baseline_model()

earlystopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.1, patience=0, verbose=2, mode='auto')

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=5, batch_size=200, verbose=2, callbacks=[earlystopper])

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
# print("Metrics(Test loss & Test Accuracy): ")
print(scores)

weight = model.get_weights()
print(weight)
```

i get the weight in array like in the picture. How can i save weight array to csv file?

[weight array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP8xJ.png)

I tried with model.save_weight() and i have an output file in h5 format but when i want to open it with numpy its only display a little part of that . I am thingking when i can save it in csv format i will get full display of the data.

I had tried to convert h5 to csv with numpy python like in the picture

```
# to save weight after output
model.save_weights('Result/w_output.h5')
```

[Tried to display full array with numpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi9Bw.png)

Comment: You said you have tried using `pandas`, can you edit your question to include the code you have tried to save to csv?  It will be easier to answer based on what you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had succeed to save my array weight to csv by using this coding

```
weight = model.get_weights()
np.savetxt('weight.csv' , weight , fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: how do you load it afterward?

Comment: @RehimAlizadeh I just load in excel because the result in csv file

Comment: I meant how to load it to use (to predict, etc.).

Comment: @RehimAlizadeh sorry i dont use predict to load it

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want every list of numbers in its own row.
If that is the case you need to reform weight in following shape weight = [[data1, data2, data3...],[data11, data12, data13...]...]. [functions for reforming list](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list)

Then you just need to write/append it to csv file. You can use pandas or csv library.

Comment: To turn this into a complete answer you should explain how the reforming can be done and then how the reformed data can be written to a csv file.

Comment: I would do so but I can not show how to reform something if all I have is screenshot of part of data.

And adding code for second part seems dishonest without first part.

Comment: thanks you for all the response. I had edited my question and add my full code